# Open a location in Google Maps using Java

Tags: java, google-maps

I would like to open a location in Google Maps from my Java application. I've got the latitude and the longitude in a string like this:

```
String latitude = "47.272529";     // String for latitude
String longitude = "7.755237";     // String for longitude
```

How can I generate the right Google Maps link for this location and how can I open it out of my source-code? It should look like this:

```
openURL("www.maps.google.com/"+latitude+"/"+longitude);    // Open URL
```

Comment: do you want to open it inside your app or inside a browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the url

The below is actual android

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current%20Location&daddr=52.5651667, -8.7895846"));
startActivity(browserIntent)
```

This will give you the option to open in your browser or in the google maps app

This should work with Java

```
try {



                Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current%20Location&daddr=52.5651667, -8.7895846"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: I've edited my answer, The second bit of code should work with Java SE.

Comment: I'm not using Android.